# How can I add an epsilon move to FSM using Python?

Tags: python, regex, regular-language, fsm, nfa

I am using the `greenery` module to implement an [FSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine):

[image]

```
from greenery import fsm, lego

E, O = range(2)
z, o = '0', '1'

# Create the FSM
machine = fsm.fsm(
    alphabet = {o, z},
    states   = {E, O},
    initial  = E,
    finals   = {E},
    map      = {
            E : {z: O, o: E},
            O : {o: O, z: E},
    },
)

# Convert it to a regex
rex = lego.from_fsm(machine)

print(rex)
```

The problem is: How do I add those epsilon moves to and from state A? I couldn't find any examples.

Answer (score 0):

It seems [greenery](https://github.com/qntm/greenery) is a python library for **deterministic** FSMs

> This module provides for the creation and manipulation of
> **deterministic finite state machines**.

Your FSM is **non-deterministic**: Consider input 0,0: You can end up with states:

1. Even--0-->Odd--0-->Even
2. Or Even--0-->Odd--e-->A--e-->Even--0-->Odd

To use greenery, you need to manually (or via a script) transform your FSM to the equivalent [Epsilon-free](https://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/%7Ewarren/xsbbook/node35.html) FSM:

> Two FSM's are said to be equivalent if they accept exactly the same
> set of strings. Given any nondeterministc FSM, **it is always possible
> to find an equivalent one that has no epsilon transitions**. In fact,
> given a machine as defined and represented above, we can easily define
> such an equivalent epsilon-free machine. So given a machine named mach
> and defined in m/4, mis/2 and mfs/2, we will define the transitions,
> initial state and final state for its epsilon-free version named
> efree(mach) as follows: ...

and then / while you are doing this, [compute the non-deterministic equivalent FSM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N_N9Ky6tN_s).